# Is it wrong to have more than one SOLR war file sharing the same solr_home?

Tags: solr

We have two JBOSS servers, each with a SOLR war file (SOLR 3.6.1). They both share the same solr_home directory and associated sub-directories including data and index directories. At any one time, either or both war files could be processing searches or uploads  (using the DataImportHandler). We are intermittently getting Locking exceptions while processing uploads e.g.

org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/sharedDirectory/blah/blah/solr_home/././myCoreData/index/write.lock

We are also getting OutOfMemory errors which we are addressing. OutOfMemory errors can cause Lock errors so I'm not sure if fixing the OutOfMemory issue will resolve the Lock issue or is our approach wrong?

Is it valid to have two SOLR applications sharing the same solr_home, lock files etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not valid.

Your instances will be stepping on each other feet all the time. Have a look at the [SolrCloud](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud) replication (not sharding) instead (Solr 4+). Then you will have full set of data in each core.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't really find any doco on this - any reference on the SOLR wiki or elsewhere?

Comment: If you don't want to upgrade to Solr 4+, you can still use Replication  in 3.6.1 - See this link for more details - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication

Comment: You can't find any docs on not sharing an open index? That's because nobody expects you to share it. Can you open one MSWord document in two instances of MSWord? No, because they both want to write back into it. Same with Solr+Lucene indexes. They get created, updated, closed, merged, deleted, reorganized. The default mode is exclusive ownership.

Comment: @Paige Cook - yep, will probably look at implementing that.