# Multiple SOLR nodes sharing same index

Tags: solr, nosql

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712128/is-it-wrong-to-have-more-than-one-solr-war-file-sharing-the-same-solr-home), what are the thoughts on having multiple SOLR instances i.e. multiple SOLR war files, sharing the same index (i.e. sharing the same solr_home) where only one SOLR instance is used for writing and the others for reading?

Is this possible?

Is it beneficial - is it more performant than having just one solr instance?

How does it affect auto-commits i.e. how would the read nodes know the index has been changed and re-populate cache etc.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not do this. Besides not working, it doesn't make your search go any faster and it creates a single point of failure.

If your freshness requirements (how soon should new or changed content be searchable?) are an hour or longer, use a Solr master/slave configuration with replication.

If you have tight requirements for freshness, use Solr Cloud.

And it is "Solr", not "SOLR".